# Using Java for light control

Tags: java, controls, hardware

when reading Eckel's Thinking in Java, I found design for controlling Greenhouse. It really struck me, since he was mentioning in comment lines "here put the hardware code for controlling light" and stuff, and I want to know - how would I make such a simple thing, as controlling physical light, or traffic light with Java program?

How would I connect light to PC and power it, through software control?

I believe assembly language with some microcontroller is the way, but I do not intend to learn assembly language yet, so I want to know if there's possibility to do this with Java?

Thanks,
M.

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't provide precise description - what am I aiming for is to replace those "//here put the hardware code" with some real hardware code that would control the lights. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Another example is [KNX](http://www.knx.org/), a binding for it is part of [openhab](http://code.google.com/p/openhab/).

Comment: Yes, I would use openHAB, too. But maybe with Z-Wave.

Comment: Does openHab have a stack exchange page or similar?

Comment: None that I'm aware of, but the [Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/openhab) is quite active.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently been playing around with [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc). It's not too difficult to write a Java program which talks to the board over serial, with the board controlling motors, leds or the like. The Arduino programming language is quite simple and based on C so with some java knowledge this should be straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I googled this a couple of months ago. Found something called X10 and this site. Might be a start for finding more information about controlling light etc.

http://x10controller.sourceforge.net/X10Client/index.html
http://www.x10.com/homepage.htm

Answer (score 0):

Calimero NG is API develop on java for homo control.